# API alternative to Google trends

Tags: search-engine, google-search, google-trends

Is there any API that I can use to rank search terms according to their popularity? An official Google API was announced to be released, however there isn't any. Any suggestions on what I may use alternatively?

Comment: Have you seen "Simply Measure"?(https://www.bestvendor.com/apps/social-media-analytics/simply-measured)

Answer (score 17):

There are some open source API's available to Google trends.

In node: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-trends-api

In Python:
https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends

In Java: 
https://github.com/elibus/j-google-trends-api

Java client side: https://github.com/elibus/j-google-trends-client

Comment: It's not really fair to describe them as API's since Google don't officially offer API's. What these products actually are are abstractions of the web interface that the user normally gets, with some filters to remove the UI. It's not an API - just another way to collect the Google Trends page content

Comment: @1owk3y The clients themselves are APIs.

Comment: Technically they are API's, but they are not OFFICIAL Google API's, and they're certainly not supported by Google. These implementations are all illegally scraping Google Trends page results. If Google wanted, they could break all of these implementations instantly just by changing their Trends page markup. That's not very "API" like. I certainly wouldn't be treating these products like conventional API's for that reason.

Comment: @1owk3y "_These implementations are all illegally scraping Google Trends page results_," that's not right. Scraping Google is not a violation of DMCA or CFAA, however, you are breaking Google's TOS. But the violation of Google's TOS not a violation of the laws.

Answer (score 4):

For Golang [groovili/gogtrends](https://github.com/groovili/gogtrends) can be useful. It's an unofficial API wrapper which works with Google Trends. Gives the ability to get trending searches and compare search items popularity over time and by region.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/394800) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 2):

There is a php api for google trends that I've been using for almost two years without problems: http://codingfocus.com/google-trends-api

It allows to get graph, region and related queries data.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out the SimilarWeb API which provides the proportion of search traffic to a given domain over time. This metric is quite similar to what Google Trends provides.

https://developer.similarweb.com/traffic_intelligence

Full disclosure, I work at SimilarWeb.

Comment: The link / page does not exist anymore / dead...
It says:
"It appears we're not on the same page
Sorry, but the page you were trying to view does not exist."